# VideoView воспроизводит звук без изображения

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что VideoView с помощью MediaPlayer корректно воспроизводит все видео кроме 4k или Full HD разрешения. То есть звук идет нормально, а вместо изображения черный экран.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штатный mediaplayer поддерживает только ограниченное количество кодеков, причем это зависит от версии Android'а

[Список поддерживаемых кодеков](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html)

Если ваш кодек не поддерживается, надо использовать другие плееры.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема только я использую Xamarin